# Single stacked bar with array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

As i'm trying to achieve a single horizontal stacked bar using d3.js (v4).
This bar doesn't consist of any x-axis and y-axis. Below is my data used to render the chart.

```
var data = [{
    "pop1": 20,
    "pop2": 20,
    "pop3": 50,
    "pop4": 20
}];
```

Below is the d3 stack layout method

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(d3.keys(data[0]))
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone)
```

As I see this works with the above `data`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/2su4zxbz/1/)

But when i change my data some thing like this. I'm getting error.

```
var data2 = [{
    "pop1": 20,
    "count": [1, 3, 4]
},
{
    "pop2": 20,
    "count": [1, 3]
},
{
    "pop3": 50,
    "count": [1, 3, 2]
},
{
    "pop4": 20,
    "count": [1, 4, 3]
}]
```

So how to show the bar using the above data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing with the stack generator, I reckon that the easiest alternative is just creating a new data array similar to your `data`, based on your `data2`. For instance, using `reduce`:

```js
var rawData = [{
  "pop1": 20,
  "count": [1, 3, 4]
}, {
  "pop2": 20,
  "count": [1, 3]
}, {
  "pop3": 50,
  "count": [1, 3, 2]
}, {
  "pop4": 20,
  "count": [1, 4, 3]
}]

var data = rawData.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  for (var key in cur) {
    if (key != "count") {
      acc[0][key] = cur[key];
    }
  }
  return acc
}, [{}]);

console.log(data)
```

Then, you just need to pass this new array to the stack generator.

Here is your JSfiddle with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/ep1z21sg/